# Java Core: data type for variable of changing value

Tags: java, string, data-structures

it's a bit of a nooby question, but say I've got a variable that keeps getting re-initialized within a loop, what would be the best data-type to store that data temporarily?

for example:

```
String value = "";
while(file.hasNext()){
   value = file.readLine();
}
```

The reason I ask is that I know that Strings are immutable, which suggests that there is a more efficient alternative, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason I ask is that I know that Strings are immutable, which suggests that there is a more efficient alternative, am I right?

Nope. You're calling `readLine` multiple times, that's going to give you a different string reference each time. Just because the string content itself can't be changed doesn't mean that it's inefficient to change the value of a `String` *variable*. That variable value is just a reference... it's not like it's going to copy the string content on each iteration.

Do you even need the variable to be declared in the loop? Generally, I prefer to declare variables with the narrowest scope possible:

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
    String line = file.readLine();
    // Use line here
}
```

Comment: "Generally, I prefer to declare variables with the narrowest scope possible". But it requires a new memory allocation in each loop, so I would suppose it is a (tiny) bit slower. Am I right?

Comment: @user3923424: No, it doesn't. The stack frame is allocated for the whole method - you don't get extra memory allocated each time you go through the loop.

Comment: @user3923424 The heap will behave pretty much the same no matter which of the two approaches, because a new string is likely to be created every time you run the `readLine()` method. In the stack, you will still just keep a single reference to that string, it will just point to a different string in every iteration. Previous strings references might be elegible for garbage collection depending on what you did on your loop.

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of case, the best thing to do is to all the computation line by line in the `while` loop, i.e.

```
String value;
while(file.hasNext()) {
    value = file.readLine();
    //do your thing on value
    //or store data in an appropriate structure
}
```

If you really need to have a string containing your entire file, and you are not able to the data while reading it, the best thing to use is `StringBuilder`, see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

In your case, it would give:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(file.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(file.readLine());
}
String entireFile = sb.toString();
```